# When does R evaluate operands to ~

Tags: r

When does R evaluate the `formula` argument passed into `lm()`.  For example:

```
tmp <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000) + tmp
df = data.frame(x=tmp)
lm(y~x, data=df)$coefficients
```

returns

```
(Intercept)           x 
 0.01713098  0.98073687
```

This suggests that `y~x` is evaluated *after* control is passed to `lm()` because there's no `x` variable in the calling context.  However, it also suggests it is evaluated *before* control is passed to `lm()` because there's no `y` column in `df`.

In most languages the arguments are fully evaluated before being passed down the stack.  I'm probably missing something subtle here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But why don't we get `Error object x not found` at the point the formula object is created?

Comment: But x isn't in any environment at that point, it's just a column on the df object

Comment: Does this mean that in `expr1 ~ expr2` it implicitly treats `expr1` and `expr2` as strings, rather than evaluating them, at the point the formula object is created?

Comment: Inside `lm`, the parameter values are all available before evaluation begins, in this case, both `formula` and `data`. Since `formula` depends on `data`, and we don't want the caller to be concerned with the order of arguments when calling `lm`, evaluation occurs in the function body of `lm`. I guess this will be true of formulas in general; they are not evaluated immediately when they occur as an argument.

Comment: @AlexZeffertt for a deeper look at what's going on under the hood, you may enjoy the Advanced R book, specifically the [Chapters on Metaprogramming](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html). Formulas are directly addressed [in this section](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#quosure-impl), but starting earlier will give you the context to understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula indicator `~` is really just a function that captures unevaluated symbols. It's a lot like `quote()` where you can run `quote(f(x)+1)` and get back the unevaluated R expression for the syntax you pass in. The main difference is that `~` allows you to have two sets of unevaluated expressions, and that the formula will keep track of the environment where it was created. So these are the same

```
a ~ b
`~`(a, b)
```

So you can pass any valid R syntax into a formula, it doesn't have to be a variable name. The values are stored as un-evaluated symbols or calls. So the formula call itself is evaluated, but its parameters are not.

Other functions can use these formulas however they like. The `lm()` function for example will pass the formula to `model.matrix`. Then `model.matrix` will attempt to evaluate the variables found in the formula in the data.frame that was passed to the function, and, if not present there, the environment where the formula was created. Different functions may choose to evaluate formulas in different ways so it's really not possible to say with certainty when the evaluation will happen.

It usually happens something like this

```
myformula <- a~b
b <- 4
dd <- data.frame(a=1:3)
eval(myformula[[2]], dd, environment(myformula)) +    # a
  eval(myformula[[3]], dd, environment(myformula))    # b
# [1] 5 6 7
```

The symbols are looked up in the environment/list passed to the evaluator.

The `environment` part is also relevant because you can also have situations like this

```
b <- 10
foo <- function(myformula = a~b) {
  b <- 4
  dd <- data.frame(a=1:3)
  eval(myformula[[2]], dd, environment(myformula)) + 
    eval(myformula[[3]], dd, environment(myformula))  
}
foo()
# [1] 5 6 7
foo(a~b)
# [1] 11 12 13
```

If you call foo without a parameter, the formula is created by default inside the function body so it will look for the value `b` there. But if you call foo with a formula, that formula is evaulated in the calling environment so R will look for the value of `b` outside the function for most modeling functions. Again, this is just a convention and non-base R package may choose to do something else.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I didn't know about `quote`. I guess the key thing is that the object created by ~ is saving some structured text for each operand, and a pointer to an environment, and that because it's a core language feature it is able to tell the interpreter to not evaluate its operands. Nifty!

Comment: Yes. That's now a lot of the "non-standard evaluation" magic in R works. But to be clear the values are not stored as text, they are stored as parsed symbols/calls as they would appear in the unevaluated abstract syntax tree as created by the R parser. You would need to coerce those values back into strings if you needed them as such.

Comment: @AlexZeffertt:  one response/correction to your comment:  *any* function can choose to evaluate its arguments or keep them as unevaluated expressions.  Use `substitute(arg)` to get the unevaluated expression passed as `arg`.  The thing that is special about `~` is that the parser allows it to be used as an infix operator; most functions need to use `fn(...)` syntax.